# Trouble getting react-suite to work within Gatsby project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby, rsuite

I'm just starting out developing with Gatsby (or doing frontend in general) and I wanted to add a Navigation bar to my website using [React Suite](https://rsuitejs.com/). However, when importing the corresponding stylesheet in my `index.js`:

`import 'rsuite/lib/styles/index.less';`

I get the following message when running `gatsby develop`:

```
ERROR #98124  WEBPACK
Generating development JavaScript bundle failed
Can't resolve 'rsuite/lib/styles/index.less' in '/Users/.../src/pages'

If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'rsuite/lib/styles/index.less' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.

File: src/pages/index.js:14:0

failed Building development bundle - 7.237s
ERROR in ./src/pages/index.js 14:0-38
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rsuite/lib/styles/index.less' in '/Users/.../src/pages'
@ ./.cache/_this_is_virtual_fs_path_/$virtual/async-requires.js 31:11-33:5
@ ./.cache/app.js 17:0-52 28:0-70 30:27-40 28:0-70

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

I tried so many things already: installing and reinstalling `rsuite`, installing and reinstalling `gatsby-plugin-less` and `less`, clearing the cache, trying all kinds of configurations in `gatsby-config.js`, but I'm out of options really.

Meanwhile, installing `react-bootstrap` and importing the stylesheet similarly through

`import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";`

does not produce the error and the stylesheet gets applied.

Would greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using:

```
import '~rsuite/lib/styles/index.less';
```

Notice the `~`, as it is inferred from [the docs](https://rsuitejs.com/guide/themes/).

Comment: Unfortunately, the same result:

Can't resolve '~rsuite/lib/styles/index.less' in '/Users/.../src/pages'

If you're trying to use a package make sure that '~rsuite/lib/styles/index.less' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.

Comment: What about `rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-default.css`?

Comment: Just to be sure... Have you run `yarn add rsuite` (or `npm i rsuite --save`) and `gatsby clean` before?

Comment: Yeah, did that! What's funny is also that I can in fact do `import { Button } from "rsuite";` which produces an unstyled button with no errors, but the stylesheet refuses to load

Comment: That's odd. Maybe you find this resources useful: https://dev.to/jacobknaack/building-and-designing-a-portfolio-site-using-gatsby-js-and-cosmic-js-2de7, https://gitter.im/rsuite/rsuite?at=5d9c3fce045925467213b73d and https://rsuitejs.com/guide/use-next-app/ (approach using next but maybe it can be applied to Gatsbby)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import "rsuite/src/styles/themes/default/index.less"
```

https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite/blob/next/examples/with-gatsby/src/pages/index.js#L4